# ininfinite loop in promise catch with callback error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm pretty convinced I'm misunderstanding how promises work but lots have reading has failed to resolve my issue.

I've got existing code that calls another module that's just been changed to use promises. Using the old version looked like this:

```
function(params, cb) {
  .....
  asyncFunc(p1, (err, res) => {
    if (!err)
       .....
       cb(null,'msg');
    else
       cb(err);
  };
};
```

changing this to:

```
function(params, cb) {
  .....
asyncFuncwithPromise(p1).then(res = > {
    ...  // X
    return cb(null,'msg');
}).catch(err => {
    cb(err);
});
```

If the code at line X throws an exception this goes into an infinite loop of catch()->then().  Removing the callback from the catch and everything's fine. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I never experienced this but written code similar to this. Has something to do with your `asyncFuncwithPromise` and the `cb`. How is your function used and how `asyncFuncwithPromise` is defined?

Comment: Need to see that CB function. Is it doing what you expect? What does it return and/or do?

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into the CB function (it's not mine), I just wanted to check that the basics of what I'm doing aren't misguided.

Comment: Nothing wrong in the pseudo code you posted.  We'd have to see the real code (including what happens in the passed in callback) in order to advise where the infinite loop is coming from.  The question as is probably cannot be answered.

Comment: Now you are working with promises, make your function "thenable" by returning a promise. Now purge the `cb` from the function - it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how an infinite loop would be created here unless `cb()` is calling `asyncFuncWithPromise()`.

I like to think of Promise callback chains as two parallel tracks. To continue down the success (`then()`) track, use the `return` keyword. To continue down the failure (`catch()`) track, use the `throw` keyword. The chain's track can be switched at any time, but callbacks will only execute linearly; that is, a callback defined earlier in the chain cannot execute after one defined later. The chain always pushes forward and cannot enter into a cycle.

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(()=>{ // 1S
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))
      return "success"; // continue down "success" (then) track
    else
      throw "fail"; // continue down "failure" (catch) track
  })
  .then(r=>{ // 2S
    return "all good: " + r;
  })
  .catch(e=>{ // 2F
    // use 'return' to recover, continue down "success" track
    return "recovered from error: " + e;
  })
  .then(r=>{ // 3S
    console.log(r); // always executed
  })
  .catch(e=> { //3F
    console.error(e); // never executed
  });
```

In this example, the final success link (3S) in the chain with `console.log()` will always be executed because the `catch()` link (2F) used `return` to get the chain back on the success track. Of course, the failure track can be followed for multiple links if each link uses the `throw` keyword.

When creating a new Promise with the `Promise` constructor, the success and failure tracks initially correspond to the `resolve` and `reject` functions supplied in the resolver. So, there is no difference (functionally) between this:

```
function getPromise(...) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    /* do something... */
    if (condition) {
      resolve(result);
    } else {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

and this:

```
function getPromise(...) {
  return Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
    /* do something... */
    if (condition)
      return result;
    else
      throw error;
  });
}
```

The difference between these subtly relates to how links in Promise chains defer to run-time event frames. This may vary among implementations, but usually a `then()` or `catch()` callback is deferred to the executing frame's next successor.

Comment: Nice tutorial about some aspects of promises, but I'm unsure how this answers the OP's question.

Comment: @jfriend00 heh, yea, I recognize it probably doesn't help the question. But from what he has presented, there's no way to know what's happening. The only way it can go into a cyclic loop is if his `cb()` is calling `asyncFuncWithPromise()`. I was trying to clarify Promise mechanics with hopes it might trigger an "aha" moment.

Comment: I guess I can see you're trying to help, but we'd really like to have the OP clarify their question so it is clear to all rather than trying to guess what might help.

Comment: There is, in fact, a difference between the two examples. The former will be executed synchronously, the latter asynchronously.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - I don't think it's a noticeable difference because, the only way you see the resolved promise is via a `.then()` handler to the returned promise which is ALWAYS called async.  So, the caller only sees an async resolution anyway.

Comment: @jfriend00 Not when you have side effects which count on order of execution. One of the biggest thing a Promise solves with `.then()` is that it's always executed asynchronously, whereas in traditional callbacks, you wouldn't be able to tell unless you went in and read the source code for the function you call. This is an important distinction.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - I guess I don't know what you're arguing.  I thought you were commenting about the difference between the last two code blocks in this answer.  A caller using `getPromise(...).then()` will see no difference between the two scenarios in the last two code blocks of this answer.  Both will execute then `.then()` handler asynchronously 100% of the time.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm talking about the difference between the `new Promise` constructor, and the `Promise.resolve().then()` approach. A Promise constructor is always executed synchronously, and a `.then()` callback is always executed asynchronously.

Comment: @DRAB - `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers are ALWAYS executed asynchronously in any standards-conforming promise implementation.  This is not "up to the implementation" to decide.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Yeah, but there's no difference in those two code blocks to the outside world (to the caller of `getPromise()`).  So, a slight difference in implementation internally does not show to the outside world at all.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes,  I had hoped that would be implied in the last paragraph...
jfriend00 You're right, however there may be odd cases in which you wish to ensure the code inside the resolver function is not run synchronously. In these cases, the latter example should be used to ensure deferral of execution. Of course, being aware of this subtlety, as both of you are, allows programmers to use the great tools of Promises with even better proficiency!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - OK, DRAB's comment has finally helped me understand the distinction you may have been pointing out.  Some of the code internal to `getPromise()` (where it says `do something`) runs with different timing in the two implementations, though the caller of `getPromise().then(...)` does not see a difference in when their `.then()` handler is called.